# Обьясните как здесь работает метод ball.score

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame  
import sys  
import random 
from pygame_Ball import Ball
pygame.init()
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400))  
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")  
icon = pygame.image.load("Gun/icon2.png") 
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)  
Clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT , 1000)  

BLACK = (0,0,0)

Text = pygame.font.Font(r"C:\Users\77761\Desktop\Sborki/Text.otf",25)
Text_render = Text.render("SCORE : " ,1 , BLACK) 
Text_pos = Text_render.get_rect(center = (75,30))

Running = True  
WIDTH = 600  
HEIGHT = 400
WHITE = (255,255,255)  
RED = (255,0,0) 
BLUE = (0,0,255)
GREEN = (0.255,0) 
FPS = 60  

balls_images = ({"path" : "Bomba.png" , "score" : 100},
                {"path" : "Bomba2.png" , "score" : 150},
                {"path" : "Bomba3.png" , "score" : 200})

balls_surf = [pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\77761\Desktop\Sborki/" + score["path"]).convert_alpha() for score in balls_images]
town = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\77761\Desktop\Sborki/town.jpg").convert()  
town1 = pygame.transform.scale(town , (600,428))  
Lovitel = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\77761\Desktop\Sborki/Lovitel.png").convert_alpha()
Lovitel_rect = Lovitel.get_rect(centerx = WIDTH // 2 , bottom = HEIGHT - 5) # bottom - если что нижние координаты прямоугольника
speed = 10


def create_ball(group):
    indx = random.randint(0 , len(balls_images) - 1)
    x = random.randint(20 , WIDTH - 20) 
    speed = random.randint(1,5)  

    return Ball(x , speed , balls_surf[indx] ,balls_images[indx]["score"], group)

game_score = 0

def collidepoint():
    global game_score  
    for ball in balls:
        if Lovitel_rect.collidepoint(ball.rect.center):
            game_score += ball.score # Как работает ball.score и почему он написан именно так
            print(game_score)
            ball.kill()

balls = pygame.sprite.Group() 

while Running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()  
        elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            create_ball(balls) 

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        Lovitel_rect.x -= speed 
        if Lovitel_rect.x < 0:
            Lovitel_rect.x = 0  
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        Lovitel_rect.x += speed
        if Lovitel_rect.x > WIDTH - Lovitel_rect.width:
            Lovitel_rect.x = WIDTH - Lovitel_rect.width

    
     
    collidepoint()
    sc.blit(town1 , (0,0))
    sc.blit(Text_render , Text_pos)
    TEXT = Text.render(str(game_score) ,1 , BLACK)
    sc.blit(TEXT , (135,15))
    balls.draw(sc) 
    sc.blit(Lovitel , Lovitel_rect)
    pygame.display.update() 
    balls.update(HEIGHT)
    Clock.tick(FPS)


# Работа самого обьекта
import pygame  

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self , x ,speed, surf , score,  group):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  
        self.score = score
        self.image = surf
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x,0))
        self.speed = speed 
        self.add(group)

    def update(self,*args):
        if self.rect.y < args[0] - 20:
            self.rect.y += self.speed  
        else:
            self.kill()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
    for ball in balls:
        if Lovitel_rect.collidepoint(ball.rect.center):
            game_score += ball.score

...

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self , x ,speed, surf , score,  group):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  
        self.score = score
```

`score` - это **поле** класса `Ball`, тут просто перебираются объекты класса `Ball` и суммируется поле `score` всех этих объектов.

**Поле** - это переменная внутри класса, а **метод** - это функция внутри класса.
`score` - это переменная, а не функция.